# Can I Install local/chromium on a S3 and use it with puppeteer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I need to install local/chromium on lambda but it's too big to be stored so, it's possible to stored it in a bucket and use it on my lambda where the code/node_module is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can use [aws lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) and use it within a lambda

Looks like there already a use case for you https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer , [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57408181/13126651)

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( I get this Exception  "Failed to launch the browser process!\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING:

Comment: check your node version and people have solved this issue here  https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/issues/82